# How do I print out all the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, printing

[Here is a screenshot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHyTv.png)I built for loop within another for loop and created a list in between the loops. I want to print out the result of every list after the second loop. However, I realize it is only going to print the last result due to the place I created my list. How am I suppose to fix it?

I am thinking of using two separated for loop, but I am not exactly sure how to do it

```
for x in range(row_number):
    row = []
    for y in range(column_number):
        cell_letter = input("Please enter either a letter or a block(*)")
        if cell_letter == "*":
            row.append("*")
        else:
            row.append(cell_letter)
    print("Next row!")

print(row)
```

the output only gives the last result of the loop

Comment: please define the "row" variable outside the for loop

Answer (score 0):

> Row variable should be defined outside the for loop.

```
row = []
for x in range(row_number):
  for y in range(column_number):
    cell_letter = input("Please enter either a letter or a block(*)")
    if cell_letter == "*":
        row.append("*")
    else:
        row.append(cell_letter)
   print("Next row!")

 print(row)
```

Comment: the result will be in the same list...is it possible to get different lists in separated line?

Comment: rows = []
for x in range(row_number):
  row = []
  for y in range(column_number):
    cell_letter = input("Please enter either a letter or a block(*)")
    if cell_letter == "*":
        row.append("*")
    else:
        row.append(cell_letter)
   print("Next row!")
rows.append(row)

for row in rows: print(row)

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
    print("Next row!")

print(row)
```

The `print(row)` executes after both loops have finished.
If you want the `print` to execute `row_number` times,
make it part of the `x` loop by indenting it four spaces:

```
    print("Next row!")

    print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get your result:-

```
row = []   # Create row outside of `for` loop
for x in range(row_number):    
    for y in range(column_number):
        cell_letter = input("Please enter either a letter or a block(*)")
        row.append(cell_letter)  # In both the cases you are simplly appending cell_letter
        print("Next row!")

print(row)
```

I hope it may help you.